# Php regex: Count occurencies

Tags: php, regex

I have this message:

```
"Hello Gabriella  :0001:  :0002:"
```

The `:0001:` and `:0002:` are actually smileys, and I want to count how many smileys are there in the message using regex. I need to count `:any number:` using regex, can you help me creating the expression.

Comment: We can help you fix your code. Please post.

Comment: I dont have any code, i just need a regex which will count those in a string: ":0001:", or any number between colons :(

Comment: Then the question is off-topic. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$message = "Hello Gabriella :0001: :0002:";

preg_match_all("(:[0-9]{4}:)",$message,$matches);

var_dump(count($matches[0]));
```

The count for that is 2.

Good luck!!

Comment: thank you, it is amazing and simple, i tried a lot but i failed, actually i am not master in regex :(

Comment: is it possible to limit to 4 digit number between the colon?

Comment: Yes, replace the `+` with `{4}`

Comment: i did it alone: "(:[0-9]{4}+:)"

Comment: You might want to update your answer with the updated regex constraining to just 4 digits.

Comment: @RuslanDascal It would be nice if you accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "Hello Gabriella :0001: :0002: :0002: :0002: 1000";

if ( preg_match_all ( '(:[0-9]{4}:)', $a, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

This counts all 4-digit numbers

You can check it out here [3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/o7cZC)

Comment: i just posted a link to an online php sandbox. it works.

Comment: 1.- The colons should be inside the capturing group 2.- You should use `preg_match_all` instead 3.- Your count is wrong, it should be: `print_r(count($matches[0]));`